# How to print LaTeX in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Python, I have LaTeX code that I print as:

```
print('Lane-Emden Equation')
display(Latex(r'$'\
              r'\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\xi}'\
              r'\left( \xi^2 \dfrac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}\xi} \right)'\
              r'='\
              r'-\xi^2\theta^n'\
             r'$'))
```

How would I print the same thing in Julia?

Comment: https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code (note `\text` does not work and you need to use `\mathrm` instead):

```
using LaTeXStrings

lat = L"""\dfrac{\mathrm {d}}{\mathrm {d}\xi} \left( \xi^2 \dfrac{\mathrm {d}\theta}{\mathrm {d}\xi} \right) = -\xi^2\theta^n"""

using PyPlot
PyPlot.cla()
PyPlot.text(0.5,0.5,lat)
```

[image]